# AOSP (Android 9) build regenerates every time I run make

Tags: android, makefile, build, android-source, ninja

When I run make at the top of my Android build, I get a notice that build files need regenerated every time, regardless of whether or not I change any files.

`$(shell development/vndk/tools/header-checker/utils/create_reference_dumps.py -products <my product> -l libtinyalsa) was changed, regenerating...`

Where is the correct place to debug why this happening?  If I use `make showcommands`, I notice there are other create_reference_dumps.py invocations before this specific invocation that pass without causing a regeneration.  Only the last one with `-l libtinyalsa` fails each time.  My previous Android 8 build tree didn't have this issue.

Comment: This was fixed in a newer version of Android. I never did figure out how to debug it though in case something similar pops up again.